# Prélever « de » ou « sur » un compte

Tags: prépositions

Pourtant de langue maternelle française, je n'arrive pas à déterminer s'il y a une version plus correcte que l'autre entre:

- La banque a prélevé le montant **sur** mon compte
- La banque a prélevé le montant **de** mon compte

Peut-être que les deux sont corrects, mais dans ce cas, y a-t-il une version privilégiée ou une différence de sens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*De mon compte* est possible mais *sur mon compte* semble plus naturel.

Avec un verbe comme *transférer*, on utilisera *de* pour indiquer la source et *vers* pour indiquer la destination:

> *Transférer le montant **de** mon compte en Suisse **vers** mon compte aux Bahamas*.

Avec *prélever*, le sens de l'opération est explicite et il n'est pas nécessaire de le préciser à nouveau. *Sur* ou *dans*, *à*, *au*, *sous*, etc. indiquent l'origine et *de* pourrait indiquer ce qui est prélevé.

> *La banque a **prélevé*** (quoi ?) ***de*** l'argent (où ?) ***sur*** mon compte.
>
> *On a **prélevé** un échantillon d'eau **dans** la cuve.*
>
> *L'ADN a été **prélevé sous** ses ongles.*

---

Google Ngram montre qu'il n'y a pas photo entre *prélevé sur* et les autres prépositions :

[image]

Comment: Je trouve cette explication, la plus convaincainte de toutes. Merci.

Answer (score 0):

Personnellement j'y vois une nuance de sens.

- La banque a prélevé le montant sur mon compte X :
  Je parle de la somme déposée sur mon compte X, le résultat est qu'il y a moins d'argent.
- La banque a prélevé le montant de mon compte X :
  Je parle de mon compte X (et pas de mon compte Y), je ne vois pas la somme en moins mais l'acte d'avoir prélevé.

Answer (score 0):

Il est vrai qu'il... est plus facile de **déposer**... **de** l'argent **sur** ton compte... sans la moindre hésitation donc. :-)

Après... bien que ne lisant que *prélever sur* dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9lever) et trouvant *prélever sur* employé dans ce contexte précis par l'[Académie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/pr%C3%A9lever), il faut quand même rappeler que la préposition *de* est copieusement utilisée quand il s'agit de marquer la provenance.

Ainsi je trouve un *prélever de* tout aussi légitime et... j'irais même d'ailleurs jusqu'à le préférer s'il s'agissait de... **fonds**, tant je trouverais pour le moins absurde que l'on *prélève des fonds sur*... :-)

Au-delà de ce seul emploi, le *de* pour signifier la provenance s'impose tout naturellement dans le contexte de *virements* pour lesquels il s'oppose à un *sur* de destination... au point que s'il n'y avait l'usage... je serais tenté de le privilégier.

Ha! Au fait, je n'ai jamais entendu *prélever **dans*** dans ce contexte... il ne serait pas non plus incongru.

Answer (score 0):

En fait, *prélever*, c'est *enlever* : on **enlève de** quelque chose, alors qu'on **ajoute sur** (ou dans) quelque chose.

Pour moi, *prélever sur* est un contresens, et il faut dire :

- la banque a *prélevé* le montant *de* mon compte;
- la banque a *déposé* le montant *sur* mon compte.

Answer (score 0):

L'emploi d'une préposition semble [complexe](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/rdp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=&page=../preposition).

Personnellement, j'aurais utilisé la préposition « sur » parce qu'elle est associée au mot « compte » dans des citations de dictionnaire : « virer une somme sur un compte » et « un montant de cent euros a été prélevé sur son compte ».

D'ailleurs, pour s'en convaincre, il faut considérer le sens du mot compte, c'est-à-dire, ne pas considérer un compte comme uniquement « une caisse contenant de l'argent ». De plus, au niveau sémantique, la préposition « sur » permet de mieux percevoir la séparation entre les mots « montant » et « compte ».